# MathJax sometimes fails to load math equation in Android

Tags: android, webview, mathjax

I have put MathJax into my project to display math equations on my app, it appears to be working, however, on some situations it just fails to load. I cant reproduce when does it happen since it happens randomly.

I can see in WebView that MathJax is being loaded, but it occasionally fails to find latex code - it doesnt gray out the latex code, it just ignores it and displays it raw. But it bugs me that on the next try when i try to load the same code - Mathjax finds it and displays it properly.

**SIDE NOTE**

I am using Activity that has Fragment ViewPager and within those fragments, WebView is being created that loads MathJax. It is interesting that - when i start that Activity (Fragment and that Webview is created instantly along with other Views). On some lower performance devices it NEVER displays latex code on the first page (latex doesnt gray out, and raw code is displayed even though MathJax gets loaded).

Also the activity where i want to load MathJax has some memory heavy stuff like bitmaps (which is being recycled when destroying item via ViewPager).

That makes me think that maybe due to some sort of lag, it fails to load?

**CODE** that loads MathJax into WebView:

```
public static void createWebView(WebView view,String questionHtml) {
    // i get string in HTML format so i parse it here
    // HTML example code: "<p>This is the equation that is being sent: <span class="math-tex">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p>"
    final String question = Html.fromHtml(questionHtml).toString();
    final WebView w =  view;
    w.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
            + "MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
            + "showMathMenu: false, "
            + "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], "
            + "extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], "
            + "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
            + "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] } "
            + "});</script>"
            + "<script type='text/javascript' "
            + "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
            + "></script><span id='math'></span>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");

    w.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (!url.startsWith("http://bar")) {
                return;
            }
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                w.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
                w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='"
                        + doubleEscapeTeX(question)
                        + "';");
            } else {
                w.evaluateJavascript("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);",null);
                w.evaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='"
                        + doubleEscapeTeX(question)
                        + "';",null);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

**BONUS QUESTION** Is there any way to hide this Loading info that displays status inside WebView?

[image]

**BONUS QUESTION SOLVED** With help of Peter Krautzberger, just add:

`+ "messageStyle: 'none', "` inside your URL below `+ "MathJax.Hub.Config({ "`

**UPDATE**

Now i can 100% percent confirm that load possibility of a MathJax completely relies on device performance, i've been trying it with:

Samsung Galaxy Note 10 (around 80% load chance)

Samsung Nexus 5 (50% chance)

and ZTE Blade G (almost never)

Also, after some research, i've found some issues that multiple WebViews that loads MathJax just fail to load in the same activity at the same time which brings me to some sort of conclusion that WebView is poorly optimized. Correct me if i am wrong or if my load code is bad (i really wish that it is).

The worst part of it all is that there are many questions out there without any clear answer why is that happening.

**PARTIAL SOLUTION**

Started using [MathView](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView) library and changed from MathJax to KaTex and it appears to load much faster with 100% chance on all devices. Side effect is that KaTex is a little bit uglier but it does its job in the end of the day.

Comment: I don't know Android at all, but it seems likely that onPageFinished will happen before MathJax is ready, so your calls to the MathJax Queue will run empty.

Comment: [edited] As for the message, check [the MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/hub.html) for `showProcessingMessages` and `messageStyle`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've set it to be hidden via `messageStyle = 'none'`. Ill see if i can get the first issue fixed, but i think that you are right about that.